# JavaFx Treeview reorder items by drag-and-drop

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, treeview

I have a treeview of hierarchical data that represents elements retrieved from a database.  I would like to be able to move child (leaf) nodes from one parent to another and rearrange the sequence of leaf nodes within a parent via drag-and-drop, finally updating the database with the results of the move operations.

Right now I can drop one of the leaf nodes onto a parent node which allows me to add the child to the parent.  However, I don't really see how to drop a leaf node between two other leaf nodes, either in the same parent or in a different parent node.

I would like to be able to do something like the following.  Starting with a tree that looks like this:

```
Root
|
+-+-P1
| |
| +--L1a
| +--L1b
|
+-+-P2
  |
  +--L2a
  +--L2b
```

For example, I would like to be able to select `L2a` and drag it up and drop it between `L1a` and `L1b`.  Or before `L1a`, or after `L1b`.  Having done that I would like to drag the child nodes of `P1` around and rearrange them via DND.

Part of this would be to provide an indication of the drop location.  For example, a line between `L1a` and `L1b` if you have the cursor positioned 'between' these nodes.

Is this possible?  I don't see any examples of this anywhere.

One other thing I am seeing is that the effect of DND doesn't remove the leaf node from its original location even though in the `setOnDragDetected` method call for my cells I call `cell.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE)`.  How can I get that to work?

**Edit 9/1/17**

I figured out the last part of not removing the leaf node.

Here is the code I am using to test this process out.  I have an interface `IStoryItem` that is the (empty) interface implemented by two subclasses, `Story` and `Part` (just to create a hierarchy to test with).  The `Story` class has `title` (`String`) and `parts` (`Part[]`) fields.  The `Part` class has `title` (`String`) and `partNumber` (`int`) fields.  I have a `Utils` class that creates an array of `Story` objects to populate my `TreeView` instance.

Here is my controller class.  It's a bit long and in need of cleanup but shows what I have tried so far.

```
public class Controller {
    public TreeView<IStoryItem> tv;
    private final DataFormat objectDataFormat = new DataFormat("application/x-java-serialized-object");

    class StoryRoot implements IStoryItem { }
    TreeItem<IStoryItem> rootItem;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        StoryRoot storyRoot = new StoryRoot();
        rootItem = new TreeItem<>(storyRoot);
        tv.setRoot(rootItem);

        // For Drag and Drop:
        // - rootItem can only accept Story nodes.
        // - Story nodes can only accept Part nodes.
        // - Part nodes can't accept any other nodes.
        tv.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<IStoryItem>, TreeCell<IStoryItem>>() {
            @Override
            public TreeCell<IStoryItem> call(TreeView<IStoryItem> siTreeView) {
                TreeCell<IStoryItem> cell = new TreeCell<IStoryItem>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(IStoryItem item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (item != null) { setText(item.toString()); }
                    }
                };

                // The following calls are as outlined in:
                // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/drag-drop.htm#CHDJFJDH
                cell.setOnDragDetected((MouseEvent event) -> {
                    // Don't drag Story nodes.
                    if (cell.getItem() instanceof Story) return;

                    // drag was detected, start a drag-and-drop gesture
                    // allow Move transfer mode only
                    Dragboard db = cell.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);

                    // Put the Part on the dragboard
                    // From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30916660/780350
                    ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                    content.put(objectDataFormat, cell.getItem());
                    db.setContent(content);

                    event.consume();
                });


                cell.setOnDragDropped((DragEvent event) -> {
                    try {
                        Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                        boolean success = false;
                        if (db.hasContent(objectDataFormat)) {
                            Part droppedPart = (Part)db.getContent(objectDataFormat);
                            IStoryItem targetStoryItem = cell.getItem();

                            // Question: How to handle drops between leaf items or
                            // before the initial leaf or after the final leaf.
                            if (targetStoryItem instanceof Story) {
                                Story story = (Story) targetStoryItem;

                                updateStoryWith(droppedPart, story);
                                addPartTo(cell.getTreeItem(), droppedPart);
                                success = true;
                            }
                        }

                        event.setDropCompleted(success);
                        event.consume();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                });

                cell.setOnDragDone((DragEvent event) -> {
                    /*
                     * the drag and drop gesture ended
                     * if the data was successfully moved, clear it
                     */
                    if (event.getTransferMode() == TransferMode.MOVE) {
                        // TODO: remove the part that got moved.
                        IStoryItem item = cell.getItem();
                        TreeItem<IStoryItem> ti = cell.getTreeItem();
                        TreeItem<IStoryItem> pti = ti.getParent();
                        pti.getChildren().remove(ti);

                        IStoryItem psi = pti.getValue();
                        boolean removed = removePartFrom(psi, item);
                    }
                    event.consume();
                });

                return cell;
            };
        });

        tv.getSelectionModel()
                .selectedItemProperty()
                .addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> inspectObject(newValue.getValue()));;

        Story[] stories = Utils.createStories();
        for (Story s: stories) {
            addStoryToTree(s);
        }
    }

    private void updateStoryWith(Part droppedPart, Story story) {
        List<Part> partsList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(story.parts));
        partsList.add(droppedPart);
        Part [] newParts = (Part[])partsList.toArray(new Part[partsList.size()]);

        int idx = 1;
        for (Part part : newParts) {
            part.partnumber = idx++;
        }

        story.parts = newParts;
    }

    private void inspectObject(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof IStoryItem)) {
            System.out.println(o.getClass().toString());
        } else if (o instanceof Story) {
            Story s = (Story)o;
            System.out.println("Story: " + s.toString());
        } else if (o instanceof Part) {
            Part s = (Part)o;
            System.out.println("Part: " + s.toString());
        }
    }

    void addStoryToTree(Story story) {
        if (story.parts.length == 0) return;
        TreeItem<IStoryItem> item = new TreeItem<>(story);
        rootItem.getChildren().add(item);
        for (Part part : story.parts) {
            addPartTo(item, part);
        }
    }

    void addPartTo(TreeItem<IStoryItem> storyItem, Part part) {
        TreeItem<IStoryItem> partItem = new TreeItem<>(part);
        storyItem.getChildren().add(partItem);
    }

    boolean removePartFrom(IStoryItem si, IStoryItem pi) {
        if (!(si instanceof Story)) return false;
        if (!(pi instanceof Part)) return false;
        Story story = (Story) si;
        Part part = (Part) pi;
        List<Part> plist = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(story.parts));
        if (!plist.contains(part)) return false;
        boolean removed = plist.remove(part);
        story.parts = plist.toArray(new Part[plist.size()]);
        return removed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically, yes this is possible. You need to use a cell factory that creates tree cells with the appropriate mouse listeners registered on them. There's an example for a `ListView` here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412445/how-to-create-a-reorder-able-tableview-in-javafx The logic for a table view will be a little more complex, as you will likely need to remove a tree item from one parent and add it to another; the same basic strategy will work though.

Comment: @James_D, I have the 'basic' DND working with a cell factory and the mouse listeners.  However, I cannot get it to drop 'between' leaf nodes.  At least it doesn't seem to be doing it.  What I need to understand is what I need to add to the listeners to get this to work.

Comment: Create a [MCVE] and post it on your question. (Similar to the answer to the question I linked.)

Comment: @James_D, done.