# TornadoFX Drag and Drop on a TreeView

Tags: tornadofx

I am new to JavaFX and, therefore, also to TornadoFX so please bear with me.

I have a simple app in Java but want to move it to Kotlin and am running into problems finding the corresponding mechanisms in TornadoFX.  I have a `ListView` holding implementations of `IStoryItem` representing Stories and Chapters.  I want to be able to move the chapters around and even from one story to another.  The `TreeView` in Java has the following implementation in its `setCellFactory` call:

```
    tv.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<IStoryItem>, TreeCell<IStoryItem>>() {
        @Override
        public TreeCell<IStoryItem> call(TreeView<IStoryItem> siTreeView) {
            TreeCell<IStoryItem> cell = new TreeCellStoryEditor();

            cell.setOnDragDetected((MouseEvent event) -> {
                // Don't drag Story nodes.
                if (cell.getItem() instanceof Story) return;

                Dragboard db = cell.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);

                // Put the Part on the dragboard
                // From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30916660/780350
                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.put(objectDataFormat, cell.getItem());
                db.setContent(content);

                event.consume();
            });

            cell.setOnDragOver((DragEvent event) -> {
                if (event.getGestureSource() != cell && event.getDragboard().hasContent(objectDataFormat)) {
                    /* allow for moving */
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
                }

                event.consume();
            });

            cell.setOnDragEntered((DragEvent event) -> {
                IStoryItem item = cell.getItem();
                if (item instanceof Story &&
                        event.getGestureSource() != cell &&
                        event.getDragboard().hasContent(objectDataFormat)) {
                    cell.setUnderline(true);
                }

                event.consume();
            });

            cell.setOnDragExited((DragEvent event) -> {
                cell.setUnderline(false);
                event.consume();
            });

            cell.setOnDragDropped((DragEvent event) -> {
                try {
                    Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                    boolean success = false;
                    if (db.hasContent(objectDataFormat)) {
                        Part droppedPart = (Part)db.getContent(objectDataFormat);
                        IStoryItem targetStoryItem = cell.getItem();

                        // Question: How to handle drops between leaf items or
                        // before the initial leaf or after the final leaf.
                        if (targetStoryItem instanceof Story) {
                            Story story = (Story) targetStoryItem;

                            updateStoryWith(droppedPart, story);
                            addPartTo(cell.getTreeItem(), droppedPart);
                            success = true;
                        }
                    }

                    event.setDropCompleted(success);
                    event.consume();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            });

            cell.setOnDragDone((DragEvent event) -> {
                if (event.getTransferMode() == TransferMode.MOVE) {
                    IStoryItem item = cell.getItem();
                    TreeItem<IStoryItem> ti = cell.getTreeItem();
                    TreeItem<IStoryItem> pti = ti.getParent();
                    pti.getChildren().remove(ti);

                    IStoryItem psi = pti.getValue();
                    // Remove the Part/Chapter from its previous Story
                    boolean removed = removePartFrom(psi, item);
                }
                event.consume();
            });

            cell.setEditable(true);

            return cell;
        };
    });
```

I have looked for something similar in TornadoFX but can't find anything that looks like it would work.  I am already using the `cellFormat` builder but I can't figure out how to add the event handlers inside it.  I see from IntelliJ's intellisense that there is also a `cellFactory` builder but I am not sure how to make use of it or how to add the event handlers to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the exact same technique in TornadoFX. Remember, TornadoFX just applies a high level API on top of JavaFX. You can always still access the underlying JavaFX API's without issue.

```
tv.setCellFactory {
    object : TreeCell<IStoryItem>() {
        init {
            setOnDragOver { event ->

            }
            setOnDragEntered { event ->

            }
            setOnDragExited { event ->

            }
            setOnDragDropped { event ->

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is odd syntax to me.  The `setCellFactory` method takes a Callback object (with a `call` method).  How does that translate to what you have here?

Comment: @melston It's called SAM Conversion (SAM = Single Abstract Method). More information can be found here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions

Comment: @RuckusT-Boom, from all the descriptions I have seen of SAM constructors I would have thought the example would have been `object: Callback {...}`

Comment: @melston That's an "object expression" (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions), which is equivalent to a Java anonymous instance. SAM Conversion is for Java lambda's, and will use the appropriate compiler optimizations in Java > 8 (which TornadoFX uses).

Comment: @RuckusT-Boom, I recognize the object expression.  But even object expressions require the type of the object being implemented, in this case a `Callback`, not the type of the argument to the SAM.

Comment: Ah, I see your confusion. The object expression in Edvin's code is the return value of the Callback, not the callback itself. The `{ ... }` around the TreeCell object expression is the SAM conversion passed to `setCellFactory` that is converted to a `Callback<TreeView<IStoryItem>, TreeCell<IStoryItem>>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154358/discussion-between-ruckus-t-boom-and-melston).