# TornadoFX TreeView cell factory not being called

Tags: tornadofx

This is related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46182788/tornadofx-drag-and-drop-on-a-treeview).

I have a TreeView in the center pane of a BorderPane layout.  This TreeView is populated by the selection of an element from a list in the left pane.  The center view looks like this:

```
class CenterView : View() {
    override val root = TreeView<IStoryItem>()
    init {
        with(root) {
            root = TreeItem(controller.storySet)

            setCellFactory {
                object : StoryEditorCell() {
                    init {
                        System.out.println("Creating StoryEditorCell")
                        onDragDetected = EventHandler {...}
                        onDragOver= EventHandler {...}
                        onDragEntered= EventHandler {...}
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
            cellFormat { ... }
            populate { ... }
        }
    }
}
```

The `setCellFactory` function is being called but, for some reason, the `init` of the factory itself is never being called.  So my Drag/Drop handlers are never set up and my `TreeCell` isn't of the correct type.

The cell format is correct and the `TreeView` is populated correctly so that part is working right.  What else needs to be done to get the cell factory correct?

Comment: This is because `cellFormat` overwrites your `cellFactory`. You must not use `setCellFactory` AND `cellFormat`. Instead, override `updateItem` inside of the cell factory. I will provide a better answer later today, and also add an API for DND to TornadoFX so you can combine it with `cellFormat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `cellFormat` actually creates a `CellFactory`, so it will effectively overwrite your configuration of a custom factory, hence your callbacks are never attached to a cell used in your TreeView.

If you manually call `setCellFactory` you must avoid `cellFormat` and instead override `updateItem` inside of the Cell to configure the text and graphic of the cell.

I looked at implementing custom support for DND so that you can combine `cellFormat` with DND without having to create a custom cell factory, but unfortunately I don't have time to begin this endeavor right now. If you feel that the current approach is cumbersome, please create an issue on GitHub and we'll get to this ASAP :)

In the mean time, remove the call to `cellFormat` and you should be good :) Remember the rules for overriding `updateItem`: Call super, clear out text/graphic, if !empty and you have a value, assign to text and/or graphic.

Also, don't do `onDragDetected = EventHandler {...}`, do `setOnDragDetected {...}` instead.

Comment: thanks.  I wasn't aware of that bit about `cellFormat`.  I'll make the change.  Keeping them separate is convenient because they are conceptually for different things.  And, I use a custom Cell-type set up to edit the contents with its own `updateItem`.  I will have to combine these all into one thing, I guess.  I think I can remove the `cellFactory` stuff and put it into the custom cell class, directly.  I assume the change from `onDragDetected EventHandler{...}` to `setOnDragDetected {...}` is due to the use of properties in TornadoFX.

Comment: Oops.  I realized I still need the cellFactory for creating the custom cell type.  I'll move the `cellFormat` stuff into the custom cell class as well.

Comment: OK.  Drag and drop is working.  I don't have my formatting but that is a small matter.  I also had to forgo the use of a custom cell for editing the names of the items shown in the treeview because I was getting a NPE when calling `super.updateItem(item, empty)`.  Not sure why that was happening when it worked in Java.

Comment: Can you post some complete code and a stack trace perhaps? It's very strange if calling super is throwing exceptions.

Comment: Well, ... I've actually moved on to a different approach.  I am using a `TextFieldTreeCell` now and dealing with the specific type of node using a custom `StringConverter`.  I would have to back up and try to find which commit showed the problem.  But, I had a custom cell inheriting from `TreeCell<IStoryItem>` (in my case) and my update method was declared as `override fun updateItem(item: IStoryItem, empty: Boolean)`.  The first thing this method did was to call `super.updateItem(item, empty)` and this is where the NPE happened.

Comment: And, from what I remember, it seemed as if the NPE was because the `updateItem` method couldn't be found.