# Issue with drag and drop setOnDragDropped operation in JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, events, javafx, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement the board game Qwirkle and I'm currently making the GUI. I'm using the JavaFX api to do this. This is what it looks like currently:

Qwirkle GUI

[image]

I'm using a border layout where the centre is my board and the left, bottom and right spaces are used for buttons and such. I am drawing the board by generating ImageView nodes at the top left and translating them to their correct locations.

I'm trying to implement drag and drop functionality where I drag the tiles at the bottom and drop them somewhere on the board. So far I have managed to get a terminal response from DragEntered and DragExited but not DragDropped and I'm at a loss. This is my code for the drag events:

```
public Tile() {
    currentTile.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            Dragboard db = currentTile.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putString("THIS HAS BEEN DROPPED");
            db.setContent(content);
            event.consume();
        }
    });
}

public BackBoardTile() {
    currentTile.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            boolean success = false;
            if (db.hasString()) {
                System.out.println(db.getString());
                success = true;
            }
            event.setDropCompleted(success);
            event.consume();
        }
    });
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Using a MacBook Pro with OS X 10.11.2 beta

Comment: Are you accepting the drag transfer on OnDragOver? See full example at http://stackoverflow.com/a/30457148

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accept the drag transfer on `DragOver` event of the target "tile" node:

```
   currentTile.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            if (db.hasString()) {
                event.acceptTransferModes( TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE );
            }
            event.consume();
        }
    });
```