# Draggable listview in JavaFX

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, listview, javafx

whilst I have found methods of re-ordering the content of a JavaFX listview I have not found a way of setting the listview itself as a drag-able object. Please let me know if there is a way of doing such a thing in JavaFX.

Thanks!

Tom

Comment: You need to set the drag handlers on the list cells, not on the list view itself. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30453919/drag-and-drop-from-listview-to-treeview for something similar.

Comment: James, thank you for your comment. Is there a JavaFX item/node that I'd be able to set a drag & drop listener to? Thanks, Tom